# How to Sum different values in mysql

Tags: php, mysql, datetime, date

I am having a small problem with mysql. I have a set of date range. Ex: starting from 01-01-2011 to 01-06-2011 and the price for this range is ex: $ 4500 per day. The next date range start from 01-07-2001 to 01-12-2011 and the price for this range is ex: $ 300 per day

If someone registered a day between ex: 05-04-2011 and 10-07-2011 I need to add the prices for number of days. In between those two date ranges, the prices are different. How can I add them separately

This is ma tbl

[image]

Thanks

Comment: what will be the rate from 02-06-2011 to 30-06-2011 ?

Comment: It's unclear what you are adding together. Do you need to get the number of days that the user was signed up under each price and then adjust the overall price based on this?  Is the amount in your table a price per day, per month, etc??

Comment: @T.Brian Jones: The amount is per day price. So form 01-01-2011 to 01-06-2011 the price is 4500 each day same as the other date range. I need to make a sum ex: if the user registered between a date range of 14-03-2011 to 08-011-2011. So the price should be calculated everyday basis for all this date range.

Comment: @binil: between 02-06-2011 to 30-06-2011, there'll be a default price range and it also should be added

Answer (score 1):

you can make one loop ...

and each time you increase date and then make query to know in which col this date value falls .. and accordingly you can isnert corresponding amount..

for that you need to manage date like how many days a month has .. and if year changes then you also need to set month to 1..

i have made one code .... to display calender . you can make chages accoringly

```
$strt_date = '01-04-2011';
$end_date = '05-07-2011';
$date_array = array();
$date_array = explode('-',$strt_date);
$back_strt_date = $date_array[2]."-".$date_array[0]."-".$date_array[1];// YYYY-MM-DD
$front_strt_date = $date_array[1]."-".$date_array[0]."-".$date_array[2];// MM-DD-YYYY
$date_array = array();
$date_array = explode('-',$end_date);
$back_bk_date = $date_array[2]."-".$date_array[0]."-".$date_array[1]; // YYYY-MM-DD
$front_end_date = $date_array[1]."-".$date_array[0]."-".$date_array[2]; // MM-DD-YYYY
// fetching data for selected date interval
//$rs_couse_cnt = get_course_cnt($back_strt_date,$back_bk_date);
if($rs_couse_cnt =='No record Found'){
    echo "No Records Found.";
    exit;
}
// converting string in to TIMESTAMP
$sdate = strtotime($front_strt_date);
$edate = strtotime($front_end_date);

//getting starting and ending month of date...
$st_dt = array();
$en_dt = array();
    // exploding date string in to array
    $st_dt = explode('-',$strt_date); 
    $en_dt = explode('-',$end_date); 

    // assigning month value to variables...
    $st_mon = $st_dt[0];
    $en_mon = $en_dt[0];

    // calculating month diff..
    $mon_diff = $en_mon - $st_mon;

    // assinging year value to variables....
    $st_year = $st_dt[2];
    $en_year = $en_dt[2];

//converting TIMESTAMP into desired date format...
$st_date = date('F jS Y',$sdate);
$en_date = date('F jS Y',$edate);

echo " <center><h2>$st_date - $en_date</h2></center>";
//echo " <br />start month is $st_mon & end month is $en_mon & month diff is $mon_diff";
//echo " <br />start year is $st_year & end year is $en_year";
$ttl_cnt =0;
for($i=$st_mon;($st_year<=$en_year);$i++){
    $end = $en_mon+1;
    if($i == $end && $st_year == $en_year){
        break;
    }
    // this will continue until all months are completed
    $st_mon_time_stamp = mktime(0,0,0,$i,1,$st_year);
    echo "<br /><br /><center> <h3> ".date("F Y",$st_mon_time_stamp)."</h3></center>";
    $no_of_days = date("t",$st_mon_time_stamp);
    $str_cal ='<table border="1px" width="100%">
                <thead>
                    <th>Sunday</th>
                    <th>Monday</th>
                    <th>Tuesday</th>
                    <th>Wednesday</th>
                    <th>Thursday</th>
                    <th>Friday</th>
                    <th>Saturday</th>
                </thead>
                <tbody>';
    $cnt = 1;
    $week = 0;
    $mon_cnt = 0;
    for($j=1;$j<=$no_of_days;$j++){
        if($cnt >= $no_of_days){
            break;
        }
        if($cnt == 1){
            // for first row....
            $time_stamp = mktime(0,0,0,$i,$cnt,$st_year);
            $str_cal .='<tr>';
            if(date("l",$time_stamp) == 'Sunday'){
                $space = 0;
            }
            else if(date("l",$time_stamp) == 'Monday'){
                $space = 1;
            }
            else if(date("l",$time_stamp) == 'Tuesday'){
                $space = 2;
            }
            else if(date("l",$time_stamp) == 'Wednesday'){
                $space = 3;
            }
            else if(date("l",$time_stamp) == 'Thursday'){
                $space = 4;
            }
            else if(date("l",$time_stamp) == 'Friday'){
                $space = 5;
            }
            else if(date("l",$time_stamp) == 'Saturday'){
                $space = 6;
            }
            $dis = 7 - $space; //exit;
            while($space != 0){
                // this will display spaces in first row...
                $str_cal .='<td>&nbsp;</td>';
                $space--; 
            }
            while($dis != 0){
                // this will display calender date in first row...
                if(strlen($i) == 1 && strlen($cnt)==1){
                    $date = $st_year.'-0'.$i.'-0'.$cnt;
                }
                else{
                    $date = $st_year.'-'.$i.'-'.$cnt;
                }
                $flg = 0;
                for($rs=0;$rs<count($rs_couse_cnt);$rs++){                      
                    if($rs_couse_cnt[$rs]['EnrolledDate'] == $date){
                        $time_stmp = strtotime($date);
                        $str_cal .='<td>'.date('j S',$time_stmp).'<br /><br />Count : <a href="light_box_course.php" onClick="$.showAkModal(\'light_box_course.php?type=list&session_id='.$session_id.'&campus_id='.$campus_id.'&strt_date='.$rs_couse_cnt[$rs]['EnrolledDate'].'&end_date='.$rs_couse_cnt[$rs]['EnrolledDate'].'\',\'\',500,500);return false;">'.$rs_couse_cnt[$rs]['CourseCount'].'</a></td>';       
                        $cnt++;
                        $mon_cnt += $rs_couse_cnt[$rs]['CourseCount'];
                        $flg = 1;
                        break;
                    }
                }

                if($flg == 0){
                    $time_stmp = strtotime($date);
                    $str_cal .='<td>'.date('j S',$time_stmp).'<br /><br />&nbsp;</td>'; 
                    $cnt++;
                }
                $dis--;
            }           
            $str_cal .='</tr>';     
        }
        else{
            // for rest of the rows...
            $str_cal .='<tr>';
            for($w=0;$w<7;$w++){
                if($cnt<=$no_of_days){
                    if(strlen($i) == 1){
                        $date = $st_year.'-0'.$i.'-'.$cnt;
                    }
                    else{
                        $date = $st_year.'-'.$i.'-'.$cnt;
                    }
                    $flg = 0;
                    for($rs=0;$rs<count($rs_couse_cnt);$rs++){
                        if($rs_couse_cnt[$rs]['EnrolledDate'] == $date){ 
                            $time_stmp = strtotime($date);
                            $str_cal .='<td>'.date('j S',$time_stmp).'<br /><br />Count :<a href="light_box_course.php" onClick="$.showAkModal(\'light_box_course.php?type=list&session_id='.$session_id.'&campus_id='.$campus_id.'&strt_date='.$rs_couse_cnt[$rs]['EnrolledDate'].'&end_date='.$rs_couse_cnt[$rs]['EnrolledDate'].'\',\'\',500,500);return false;">'.$rs_couse_cnt[$rs]['CourseCount'].'</a></td>';        
                            $flg = 1;
                            $cnt++;
                            $mon_cnt += $rs_couse_cnt[$rs]['CourseCount'];
                            break;
                        }
                    }
                    if($flg == 0){
                        $time_stmp = strtotime($date);
                        $str_cal .='<td>'.date('j S',$time_stmp).'<br /><br />&nbsp;</td>';
                        $cnt++;
                    }
                }
                else{
                    $str_cal .='<td>&nbsp;</td>';
                }
            }
            $str_cal .='</tr>';
        }
    }
    $ttl_cnt += $mon_cnt;
    if($mon_cnt != 0){
        $str_cal .='<tr>
                        <td> Monthly Count :</td> 
                        <td colspan="6"><a href="light_box_course.php" onClick="$.showAkModal(\'light_box_course.php?type=list&session_id='.$session_id.'&campus_id='.$campus_id.'&strt_date='.$st_year."-".(strlen($i)==1?"0".$i:$i)."-"."01".'&end_date='.$st_year."-".(strlen($i)==1?"0".$i:$i)."-".$no_of_days.'\',\'\',500,500);return false;">'.$mon_cnt.'</td>
                    </tr>';
    }else{
        $str_cal .='<tr>
                        <td> Monthly Count :</td> 
                        <td colspan="6">'.$mon_cnt.'</td>
                    </tr>';
    }
        $str_cal .='</tbody>
                </table>';
    if($i == 12){
        $i=0;
        $st_year ++;
    }
    echo $str_cal;  
}
```

?>

Comment: what I really need is this:
I have a hotel search form where users can come and select arrival date and departure date. The administrator can change the prices for a certain period of time. The admin assign $1000 for 15-01-2011 to 20-02-2011 and $5000 for 21-02-2011 to 30-05-2011. If a user search for a hotel between 10-01-2011 to 28-02-2011. In 21st of 2nd month, the prices changed. So I need to calculate $1000 prices from 10-01-2011 to 20-02-2011 and $5000 prices from 21-02-2011 to 28-02-2011. That would be the sum of the whole time period right. So I need to write a code how to add them.